# Why does lambda shows error in code submission

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I wrote code on notepad and then converted it to zip file (rooted zip file) but after uploading it to lambda when I click on save it shows error as "could not open file: /index.js...The file could not be found in the file system". As the code is quite lengthy so I cannot use inline function.

Comment: Is your index.js  right inside the zip file or inside a root directory

Comment: it's right inside the zip file (I converted notepad to zip file rather than putting it in a zip directory).

Comment: The structure should be like this . YouZipFile.zip --> index.js

Comment: do you mean to say I need to save the notepad file as index.js??